# Suzuki Swift Sport 2012

Tags: clutch, suzuki, gears

My car (2yrs old) needs a new clutch after 45km and Suzuki won't cover it under waranty. I'm no mechanic but the car has not been driven hard and has mainly had longer highway journeys never. Is Suzuki being fair?

Suzuki have inspected the clutch and claim that the clutch has premature wear caused by shock clutch release. The housing broke away from the centre hub which resulted in the spring jumping out.

The car is driven by a lady driver and not driven hard. For the the the past few service intervals we have raised that twas battling to get it into 2nd/3rd gear. Despite it being documented on the service request and discussed at length this was not resolved.

Please could you assist - I'm fair and if at fault then ok with having paid for a new clutch. But can't get the fact to add up..

Comment: Just to be clear: "45km" == 45000 miles, right?  Not 45 kilometers?

Comment: 45km == 45000 kilometers == 27961.7 miles.

Comment: I know this is an old thread. But all swift sport from 2012 to 2014 came from the factory with a fulty clutch disc, all fail at the clutch springs. Suzuki released 3 updated clutch discs after that version, and in the end they contracted another clutch supplier. Did you install a suzuki clutch again?

Answer (score 1):

If you look on [this website](http://www.suzukiauto.com/warranty.aspx), you can see that Suzuki has a 7 year, 100k mile power train warranty if you reside here in the States (this may be world wide, but I don't know for sure). The last time I checked, the clutch is part of the drive train. Unless they have it in writing where it states the clutch is not part of the power train warranty, it should be covered. If you have taken it to a Suzuki dealership and they refuse to fix this for you, ask them to show you in writing where this part is not covered. If they *can* show you, then I'd say you are out of luck (not sure if they consider this a *wear item* or not). If they cannot show you in writing, you might try and take it to a different Suzuki dealership, though I would bet they are fairly sparse. You are not required to utilize the dealership you bought the car at for warranty work. If a different dealership (or authorized repair facility) is not available to you or they decline to do the work as well, you will need to appeal this to corporate Suzuki for resolution (if there is nothing in writing stating about the clutch). Mind you, if corporate Suzuki says "no", again, you are probably out of luck unless you are willing to take them to court. If a company is willing to put a warranty on their product, they should be willing to back it up.

**EDIT:**

Looking further at the page mentioned above is a link to an [arbitration page](http://www.suzukiauto.com/Arbitration.aspx). This may be your legal recourse to getting your clutch fixed at Suzuki expense. It does say on there that the decision which is provided by through arbitration is binding on Suzuki, but not upon the customer.

Answer (score 0):

The Susuki Swift is a budget built volume car. The type of clutch fitted would reflect this in the quality of its build. Something like 45km (or 35000 miles) for this clutch is not a bad mileage and reflects a reasonable use and service life. When driving on the motor way, every increase and decrease in speed even whilst staying in the same gear is felt as a loading through the driven plate and diaphragm plate. This normal wear and tear would probably have caused this failure. Manufacturers do not readily accept items like clutches, brakes and tyres under warranty as thier use is at the discretion of the driver, and are vulnerable to poor driving or mis-use.